# error submitting an answer

Tags: bug

I have a question about my Unix & Linux Stack Exchange post: [Does Duplicity modify atime when backing up?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440819/does-duplicity-modify-atime-when-backing-up/478756#478756)

I was trying to post an answer to the abovementioned question. When posting my answer I got an error page instead, and now I cannot even visit that question, instead I'm redirected to an error page.

The answer I was trying to post follows after the `<HR>`

---

No, it's incorrect to say that a software application modifies the `atime` of a file. User-mode programs have almost no way to control whether the `atime` is updated. That is the responsibility of the operating system, or more specifically, the [filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) driver.  Furthermore, the current default mount options on Linux will minimize timestamp updates so that they will have little impact on performance or longevity your [ssd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssd).

The current situation on modern [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) distributions is as follows:

- Using the mount option `noatime` completely eliminates `atime` updates at the expense whatever utility is provided by maintaining `atime` metadata.
- The default `relatime` option minimizes the issue
- A recently-introduced option, `lazytime` should completely eliminate any remaining impact on SSD longevity from timestamp updates.

Comment: apparently it was a transient error because I can now visit the question and I see my answer was posted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bad build that got rolled back.

Copying [Taryn's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317515/241919):

> There was a bad build that was impacting the display [of some questions](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1057385414770769926). The build was rolled back and pages should be loading normally again.
>
> We're still investigating the bug that caused the problem in the first place, but things should be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Possibly the site went down for an update; that happens periodically and usually takes under a minute to complete.